# nested views with backbone routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, marionette, nested-routes

i would like to navigate my nested view in backbone app with routes. I have next code:

```
var StoreRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

  appRoutes: {
    'item/:name/' : 'showItem',
    "item/:name/species/:speciesName/" : "showSpecies"
  }

});

var StoreCtrl = Marionette.Object.extend({

  showItem: function(name){
    console.log("showItem");
    /* execute function for show Item */  
  },

  showSpecies: function(name, speciesName){
    console.log("showSpecies");
    /* execute function for show Species inside Item Layout  */ 
  }

});
```

So, i need to show species when route is "item/:name/species/:speciesName/" but i get only triggering showSpecies fucntion, not both. What shall i do to trigger showItem and then showSpecies functions when route is "item/:name/species/:speciesName/" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing brand new here. Simply call your `showItem` function directly from `showSpecies`.
Additionally, you could use `routes` hash instead of `appRoutes` and then it is possible to do so:

```
var StoreRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

  routes: {
    'item/:name/' : 'showItem',
    'item/:name/species/:speciesName/' : function(){
      this.showItem();
      this.showSpecies();
    }
 }
```

});

Comment: Thank u. But in my case this solution cause reloading item each time when i want to show another species. Is there a way to escape reloading item and show only proper species when /:speciesName/ changes?

Comment: @PavelPoberezhnyi of course. You could save somewhere your current item and add check at the beginning of your `showItem` function: `if (currentItem === newItem) return false;`